# Making a picture slideshow in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm new to html and css as of a couple days ago but decided to try to make a website. I want to include a slideshow of pictures, so I'm trying to do an animation but only the first picture is showing up. I'm not sure if there's a better way to do this than animations or what I'm doing wrong. Ideally, I'd like them to slide from right to left and have arrows you can click to go through the pictures as well, but I haven't figured out how to add that yet

I'm using Chrome as my browser and have cleared the cache in the browser as well as dev tools. Doing a relative path for my pictures got rid of errors I was getting in dev tools (GET file:///D:/VScodepicsIMG_1550.JPG net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND). When I was referring to a local path for the pictures, I was getting that error in dev tools for all of the pictures, but the path in the error is not the correct path of the pictures (the correct path for that corresponding error message would have been D:\VScode\pics\IMG_1550.JPG) I'm not sure what else to try. Below is my code:

html file:
`<img id="pics" src="./pics/Screenshot 2023-10-26 185458.png" >`

css file:

```
/*PICTURE SLIDESHOW*/
#pics{
    background-image: url("./pics/Screenshot 2023-10-26 185458.png");
    width: 200px;
    animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    animation-name: picsSlides;
    animation-duration: 10s;
    animation-delay: 2s;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;
}
@keyframes picsSlides{
    0% {background-image: url("./pics/Screenshot 2023-10-26 185437.png");}
    33% {background-image: url("./pics/Screenshot 2023-10-26 185411.png");}
    66% {background-image: url("./pics/Screenshot 2023-10-26 190531.png");}
    100% {background-image: url("./pics/Screenshot 2023-10-26 190614.png");} 
}
```